# How can i get the code of Shop Page Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, templates

I'm trying to write the codes of the shop page in woocommerce, especially in the main div
[image]

All of them are inside div with class-main, and I want to know how I can create one by myself with the standards code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many hooks you can use to change certain code on archive pages. [see here](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/)

it is not recommended to change template files, but if you need to, create the copy of archive-product in the child theme with same folder structure as parent theme. this will affect all archive pages, shop, archive and tags. however, you can also rename it and set up a conditional, if( is_page( archive-shop )) then display the new template.